# Parse json array to java string array

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, servlets, bootstrap-multiselect

I am building a bootstrap multiselect tool like this:

[Multiselect tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YutOt.png)

The selected values in multiselect tool are first converted into a javascript array, like this:

```
var authors = [];

$("#selectAuthors option:selected").each(function(i, value) {
    authors.push($(this).val());
});
```

Then this array is passed to servlet using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    url : "../addBook",
    data : {
        addTitle : $("#addTitle").val(),
        addPublisher : $("#selectPublisher").val(),
        addAuthors : JSON.stringify(authors),
    }
})
```

And in the servlet, the array is parsed to a java string array:

```
String[] authorNames = request.getParameterValues("addAuthors");
```

The problem is, the java string array I got in the servlet is not exactly I wanted. For example, If I select "author1" and "author2" in multiselect tool:

Expected string array I should get:

```
{"author1", "author2"}, string length: 2
```

The string I actually get:

```
{"["author1", "author2"]"}, string length: 1
```

If I just select one option in multiselect tool, like "author". In servlet, I will get this:

```
Print out authorNames[0]: ["author"]
Print out authorNames[0].length: 10  
//The legnth of "author" is 6, but the length of "["author"]" is 10
```

Can you explain where I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: replace from `JSON.stringify(authors)` to `authors.toString()`

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Yeah, I parse "authors" to string first, then use string.split(",") in servlet to convert the string to string array. It works, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I parse "authors" to string first, then use string.split(",") in servlet to convert the string to string array.